# GetManifestResourceStream in module

Tags: vb.net

I want to move the following function from a form into a module because I plan to use this function from different "locations":

```
Public Function StreamFromResource(ByVal uFilename As String) As Stream

    Dim nAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    Dim s As Stream = nAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(Me.GetType, uFilename)
    Debug.Assert(Not s Is Nothing)

    Return s

End Function
```

However, VB.NET tells me that "Me" is not valid in a module.
Can somebody tell me a workaround?

Thank you!

Comment: Me refers to the current/local Object which a module is not.  It should work to pass `Me` to the procedure As Object, or a Type avalable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
Public Function StreamFromResource(ByVal uFilename As String) As Stream

    Dim nAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    Dim s As Stream = nAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.DeclaringType, uFilename)
    Debug.Assert(Not s Is Nothing)

    Return s

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the solution posted, but the pendulum has swung to the other extreme: now it can only be used from a Module.  Here are some flexible ways to do it:

```
' no need for Public
Friend Function GetResourceStream(obj As Object, filName As String) As Stream

    Dim t As Type = obj.GetType
    Dim asm As Assembly = t.Assembly
    Dim s As Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(t, filName)

    Return s
End Function

' usage:
Dim ss As Stream = GetResourceStream(Me, strFile)
```

Even more reusable are Extensions:

```
<Extension>
Friend Function GetResourceStream(obj As Object, filName As String) As Stream

    Dim T As Type = obj.GetType
    Dim asm As Assembly = T.Assembly
    Dim s As Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(T, filName)

    Return s
End Function

<Extension>
Friend Function GetResourceStream(T As Type, filName As String) As Stream

    Dim asm As Assembly = T.Assembly
    Dim s As Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(T, filName)
    Return s

End Function
```

The first one is the easiest, but only loads from this assembly:

```
Dim s = Me.GetResourceStream(strFile)
```

The second one is a little cumbersome, but more flexible:

```
Dim s = GetType(Foo).GetResourceStream(strFile)
```

Though clumsy, it allows the Type (`Foo`) to act as a resource "locator".  If the resources are in a different assembly, define `Foo` in the same assembly to load resources from there.  Ideally, you'd use a real Type already used by your app, but when there isnt one, an empty `Foo` or `ResLocator` Class will work.

You can also redefine the extensions simply as `Friend Shared` for use in a utility class.